# Number of points of a quadric hypersurface over a finite field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-equations, rational-points, quadrics

Let $k = \mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field with $q$ elements and $Q\subset\mathbb{P}^n_k$ a quadric hypersurface defined over $k$.

By the Chevalley-Warning theorem if $n\geq 2$ then $Q$ has a point. Is there a formula for the number of points of $Q$ or at least a bound of the type $\#Q(k)\geq f(q,n)$ where $f$ is a function of $q$ and $n$?

Comment: Is $Q$ assumed smooth? If not, there could potentially be only one point.

Comment: Yes, $Q$ is a smooth quadric. I think that for $n=2$ the number of points of a smooth conic should be $q+1$.

Comment: Yes, it's known in general for nondegenerate quadrics. One place to look it up is the introduction in Atlas of Finite Groups.

Comment: For $q$ odd isn't $Q$ equivalent to $-cx_0^2+\sum_{j=1}^m x_j^2$ for some $m\le n$ ? Then there is a recursive formula for $\# \{x\in \Bbb{F}_q^m,-cx_0^2+\sum_{j=1}^m x_j^2=0\}$ in term of $m, q, \# \{x\in \Bbb{F}_q^{m-2},-cx_0^2+\sum_{j=1}^{m-2} x_j^2=0\}$ and if $-1$ is a square.

Comment: @reuns Yes, at least if $q$ is odd. Furthermore $m=n$ since Arty specified that it's smooth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. The number of points of a smooth quadric hypersurface is $\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$ if $n$ is even or $\frac{q^n-1}{q-1} \pm q^{ \frac{n-1}{2}}$ if $n$ is odd.

This can be proven in a number of ways. Here is a (perhaps extravagantly) geometric approach:

Fix a point $x$. A line through $x$ contains one other points of $Q$, unless that line is tangent to $Q$ at $x$ - in other words, is contained in the tangent plane of $Q$ at $x$. If so, then the line contains no other points of $Q$, except if the line is contained in $Q$, in which case it contains $q$ other points. So the number of points is

$$1 + \frac{ q^{n}-1}{q-1} - \frac{ q^{n-1}-1}{q-1} + qN  = q^{n-1} +1 + qN$$

where $N$ is the number of lines through $x$ that lie in $Q$, since I have taken the point $x$, added the number of lines, subtracted the number of tangent lines, and added $qN$.

Now the lines through $x$ in the tangent plane are parameterized by an $n-2$-dimensional projective space, and the lines contained in $Q$ form a quadric surface in that projective space. So the number of points on a quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n$ for $n\geq 2$ is $q^{n-1} +1$ plus $q$ times the number of points on a quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb P^{n-2}$. The formulas in above then follow by induction from the easy base cases $n=0, n=1$.

Comment: There is a typo in your formula for $n$ odd. For $n=3$ it should be $q^2+2q+1$ if the rulings are defined over the ground field and $q^2+1$ if not.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Are you sure? Plugging in $n=3$, I get $\frac{q^3-1}{q-1} \pm q = q^2+q+1 \pm q$, i.e. either $q^2+2q+1$ or $q^2+1$.

Comment: @Will Sawin. Thank you very much. Say that $n$ is even and we have a smooth quadric $Q$ containing $\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$ points. If $q$ is big enough to make the expected dimension of the space of quadrics through these points to be non positive is then $Q$ the unique quadric through the fixed points?

Comment: You are right, I misread the formula.